# openerp 7 ir.sequence increment by 2 bug.?

Tags: python, xml, sequence, odoo

In my case +1 sequence number shows when I open the form. But when I save the record, it incremented again by 1. That means my sequence numbers now look like this:

- EMP0010
- EMP0012
- EMP0014

Is it an issue with openerp or am I missing something in my code?

```
'register_no': fields.char('Register No', size=32, help='Register No', readonly=True),  # employer wise ,estate wise
        'employer_no': fields.char('Employer No', type='char', readonly=True),

_defaults = {
 'register_no': lambda obj, cr, uid, context: '/',
 'employer_no': lambda obj, cr, uid, context: '/',
 }
```

You can have a look on my code [here](https://github.com/priyankahdp/openerp/blob/openerp)

i commented

```
    def create(self, cr, uid, values, context=None):
        values['register_no'] = self.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid, 'bpl.worker')
        values['employer_no'] = self.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid, 'bpl.employer')
        return super(bpl_worker_registration, self).create(cr, uid, values, context=context)
```

Comment: Please close the question if you got answer by click on right symbol below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have called two times ir.sequence method, one from create

> def create(self, cr, uid, values, context=None):
>
> ```
> values['register_no'] = self.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid, 'bpl.worker')
> values['employer_no'] = self.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid, 'bpl.employer')
> return super(bpl_worker_registration, self).create(cr, uid, values, context=context)
> ```

and second from default

> _defaults = {
>
> ```
>  'register_no': lambda obj, cr, uid, context: obj.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid, 'bpl.worker'),
>  'employer_no': lambda obj, cr, uid, context: obj.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid, 'bpl.employer'),
>
>  }
> ```

It does not make any sense to call two time. make call only from _default or from create method

Comment: removed the function.but still same issue friend.

Comment: removed functions means removed from create method??? would you please check after restart server

Comment: see my above post now friend

Comment: yes ,when you put your code in defualt it call it two times. I have one trick here, comment code in default and pur some thi like: 'resgiser_no': lambda obj, cr, uid, context: '/', and uncomment code from create method